# Why sometimes iOS cannot open url sms on React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have a problem that I'm trying to understand: How come I receive from time to time Sentry errors telling me that an iPhone X or XR could not open the SMS url?

I have this error: **Unable to open URL: sms:&body=...**

But what's even weirder is that when I look at my Sentry breadcrumb, I realise that this error seems to happen when the user didn't even do the necessary action to open the SMS application!

The sms I send contains a URL that is generated by Firebase Dynamics Links.

Here is the code to generate the url of the sms and the code that sends the sms

```js
InviteFriends.js

export default inviteFriends = () => {
    let sharingToken = store.getState().user.share_token

    firebase.dynamicLinks().buildShortLink({
        link: `http://mywebsite?type=invite&sharing=${sharingToken}`,
        domainUriPrefix: 'https://mylink.page.link',
        navigation: {...},
        android: {...},
        ios: {...}
    })
    .then((url) => {
        sms('', i18n.t('account.addFriends.searchUser.hint.sms', {link: url}))

    })
```

```js
sms.js

const sms = (phone = '', body = '') => {
  const sep = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? '&' : '?'
  const url = `sms:${phone}${body ? `${sep}body=${encodeURIComponent(body)}` : ''}`

  const supported = await Linking.canOpenURL(url)

  if (!supported) {
    return Promise.reject(new Error('Provided URL can not be handled')) 
  }

  return Linking.openURL(url)
}
```

What I find weird is that it seems to me that if opening the SMS application wasn't supported, I'd be supposed to get a message saying "Provided URL can not be handled" instead. Am I wrong ?

Thanks you,

Viktor

Comment: Have you add mailto in LSApplicationQueriesSchemes in IOS info.plist,
Please check

Comment: I just found out about the LSApplicationQueriesSchemes, I don't understand why I should add mailto to my info.plist!
However, I went to check and I see that I have neither mailto nor sms in my LSApplicationQueriesSchemes! Could it be from there? And why do I have to edit this key? Btw thanks for your answers !